# How to keep 2 Database Schemas consistent without effecting the data at all?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two server machines (One for development, other for Clients) with SQL Server 2008 installations. Whenever a developer makes changes to tables/views/stored procedures in the Development Server, it needs to reflect the Client Server as well.

Currently, I am manually handling all changes like new columns in Tables, changes in Stored procedures etc. Can DB scripts or replication automate the entire procedure for me? Or is there some better solution to keep database schemas consistent.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to create an environment where all schema changes are done exclusively through SQL scripts - never "manually" in any environment. Each developer has to commit the script related to his/her bugfixed (or new features) to a version control system.

Typically you'd have one big script that creates the database from scratch and one for each version upgrade (from 1.0 to 1.1, one from 1.1 to 1.2 and so on)

If you have the man power it is also very handy to maintain one "from-scratch" script for each version. Whether you need that or not depends on how often an installation on an empty system is done.

We have very good experience with using Liquibase to maintain all this. It automatically keeps track which patches have been applied to a database and which need to be run during an upgrade. It also prevents you to run the same migration twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your inputs are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A problem that all database applications have, and a difficult one to resolve. Such a solution cannot be scheduled, as the changes made by developers need to be tested first, and you certainly don't want untested code merged with your live database. This question is of interest to me because I'm currently writing a generic solution to resolve this issue once and for all.

But in the meantime, we're using an open-source product called Open DBDiff (Google it - you can't miss it), which could do with some polishing but works well enough. You pass it your source and target databases, and it generates a script to make the target the same as the source. It does seem to have some trouble copying assemblies and user roles, but for everything, I haven't had any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering of developing an App for finding differences between databases, thanks to your reply, i wouldnt really need that now!

Answer (score 0):

I believe a human should do the deployments, after making sure the changes have been tested and properly checked into the source control. This is not something to automate fully.

Human should use the tools though. I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional, which has a powerful schema comparison tool, generates and executes deployment scripts and has source control integration.