# How to keep client databases consistent whenever a coder changes stored proc/table definition/views/triggers etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

**I have asked this question before ([here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206522/how-to-keep-2-database-schemas-consistent-without-effecting-the-data-at-all), but it never solved my problems.**

Here is the scenario:
1. A coder modifies a stored proc/table definition/views etc on his "development server" 
2. The modified T-SQL code is tested and passed by another team
3. Now the tested T-SQL code needs to be updated in 20 client databases. (Which is an extremely tough task). 
4. Currently, we copy paste the T-SQL code in every db individually. This also results in errors which are resolved only when the client complaints.

We are using SQL Server 2012, and I guess usage of Schema's may resolve this issue. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why not just use a database project?

Comment: As above. Can you use a database project? You can essentially compare your database project to a "Template" database your clients are on. It can then compare the two schema's to create an SQL script to provide the relevant updates or creation of new objects.

Comment: How to create a Database Project? I have no idea about that. We just have different client databases in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the bellow query. Only thing is you must have access to all the databases and all those DBs are in the same server.

```
-- Provide DB names as CSV
DECLARE @DBNames    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ExpDB,ExpDB_DUP'
-- Provide Your Update Script here
DECLARE @Script     VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE TestTab (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                    Value nvarchar(50) NULL)'

DECLARE @DBNamesTab TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(128))
INSERT INTO @DBNamesTab
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(128)'))) AS DBName
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(  '<XMLRoot><RowData>' 
                + REPLACE(@DBNames,',','</RowData><RowData>') 
                + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

DECLARE @DBName     VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ScriptExe  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE dbNameCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DBName FROM @DBNamesTab  
    OPEN dbNameCursor  
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbNameCursor INTO @DBName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
        SET @ScriptExe = 'USE ' + @DBName + ' ' + @Script
        EXEC(@ScriptExe)
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbNameCursor INTO @DBName
        END
    CLOSE dbNameCursor;  
DEALLOCATE dbNameCursor;
```